# C# перехват пакетов

Tags: c#, сеть

Как можно сделать, чтобы программа порт в браузере и перехватывала все запросы. Например в качестве прокси в браузере указывается `127.0.0.1:8181` и программа принимает все запросы по этому порту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сниффер? Тогда [вот](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C) готовый проект.